# Mailmerge 2 spreadsheets

Tags: microsoft-excel-2010, microsoft-word-2010, mail-merge

Can I mailmerge in Word 2010 using 2 Excel spreadsheets?  Have found article that says Get Data and then click Data Source but cannot find this in Mailmerge Wizard as an option.

Answer (score 1):

Word does not support multiple data sources for a mail merge. You will need to use techniques in Excel to merge the data sources.

Options include copy and paste, Microsoft Query, or -- the winner -- Power Query. It's a free add-in from Microsoft for Excel 2010 and 2013 and built into Excel 2016 as "Get and Transform". You can create queries to the two Excel files as connections only, then append the queries and save to the workbook. Then use that workbook as the source for the mail merge. When the data in the two original files changes, open the query workbook and hit "Refresh all".